# Unable to retrieve events created by a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-access-token, user-permissions, facebook-events

I have tried with EVERYTHING, graph, FQL, access_token with all permissions granted, multi-queries... now I'm really tired! Someone can tell me HOW to retrieve all the events created by a page like this? http://facebook.com/mammamiasantateresa
I want to know why this query doesn't work:

```
SELECT eid, name, description, location, pic_big, start_time, end_time, is_date_only FROM event WHERE creator = 229315807171062
```

But instead, this query with this page: 205712556144006 (/fifteenonline) who has only an event, or with Coldplay's page 15253175252 (/coldplay), who has many events, it just works!!! I wonder why. Nobody for weeks gave me a response. Please, it's very important for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your query is OK and if this would be an event it should be worked. But the thing you're looking for is a post on a wall, not an event, and it could be found via searching in stream in Graph API or FQL query:

Graph API request:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=229315807171062%2Ffeed

FQL Query request (with 2 fields, but anyway this post is there):

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20message%2C%20updated_time%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%20%3D%20229315807171062

Comment: What? 229315807171062 is the PAGE ID, exactly as the others I posted. Why this doesn't work?

Comment: Because this entry is not present in event table, it is only present in stream table. I mean you (or some other person) did not made a Facebook event, just a stream post with date and location.

Comment: I don't understand. The page "Mamma Mia" has a lot of events, exactly like the page "Coldplay". Why the query works with the latter but not with the former?

Comment: When you run event query on Coldplay, you'll see that the newest event is of September, 2012 (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=214725825272150), while their wall posts (with dates) are from more recent time. So: Coldplay has not so much events as it has posts. And your page only has wall posts with dates and places, but no events were created via event menu.

Comment: Really I ma unable understand your sentence. The events in the "Mamma Mia beach" are created like EVENTS, nothing to do with "simple stream posts with location and date". This event: https://www.facebook.com/events/493277804051260/ is an event exactly like this https://www.facebook.com/events/520268914652502/ and this: https://www.facebook.com/events/215823701820387/